# A "good" basis for $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C} - \{0,1,\infty\})$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_\infty$ denote three small positively oriented loops winding once around $0,1,\infty\in\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ respectively (they are each contained in a tiny contractible neighborhood of $0,1,\infty$).

Let $x_0,x_1,x_\infty$ lie in the images of $\gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_\infty$ respectively.

Let $\delta : x_0\leadsto x_\infty$ be a path. Consider the two statements:

1. $\gamma_0$ and $\delta^{-1}\gamma_\infty\delta$ generate $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1 - \{0,1,\infty\},t_0)$.
2. There exists a path $\epsilon : x_0\leadsto x_1$ such that $\gamma_0\epsilon^{-1}\gamma_1\epsilon\delta^{-1}\gamma_\infty\delta = 1$

Are these two statements equivalent?

If this is addressed in some book/paper references would be appreciated as well!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are saying $\mathbb P ^1$ instead of $S^2$? What is the context of this question? Would be interesting to know.

Comment: @NoelLundström Not really, I may as well say $S^2$, but I'm more of an algebraic geometer so I tend to think of it as $\mathbb{P}^1$. The context is that I'm doing some Galois-theoretic calculations which involve choosing a path $\delta$, and at some point I need to assume that $\delta$ satisfies both (1) and (2). Certainly such $\delta$ exist, but I'm curious if (1) and (2) are actually equivalent.

Comment: @NoelLundström It is common for algebraic geometers to refer to $S^2$ solely as $\mathbb{P}^1$. I believe it is supposed to reflect the fact that it plays the role of a line in projective geometry.